# Can I save the hanging girl?

Tags: cryptozookeeper

More [Cryptozookeeper](http://www.joltcountry.com/index.php/robbsherwin_videogame/cryptozookeeper): I was going after the ape in the corporate lab when I found a woman hanging from the ceiling of a work room, partially encased in crystals. Scanning her reveals that she's still alive, only unconscious. However, most attempts to interact with her are failures.

Not to gloss over the details too much, but I've liberated the ape, and get the feeling that I can leave the area safely—which probably means I won't be coming back.

Can the woman be saved, somehow? And if so... how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unfortunately. There is no way to save her.